# How to take multiple files in terminal in BASH shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am new in sh and I am trying to scan output files and take some rows starts with "enthalpy new" to a new file. In advance I created a file named step.txt in the directory. There is not a certain number of files so I tried to do it like that:

```
     for (( i=1; i<=$# ; i++))
     do
     grep "enthalpy new" $i >> step.txt
     done
```

And I wrote this command to the terminal:

```
     $bash hw1.sh sample2.out sample1.out
```

Then, I took these errors:

```
     grep:  1: No such a file or directory
     grep:  2: No such a file or directory
```

I am expecting to have step.txt file having 28 lines which 12 of them coming from sample1.out and 16 of them coming from sample2.out. Inside of step.txt will look like:

```
  enthalpy new = 80 Ry
  enthalpy new = 76 Ry
  ....
  ....
  enthalpy new = 90 Ry
```

Is there anyone to tell my error and to help me fixing the code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Good that you have shown your efforts keep it up. Could you please show sample of input and expected output in your question for better understanding of your question in your question(not in comments), thank you.

Comment: Just do grep "enthalpy new" sample1.out sample2.out >> step.txt. There is no need for a loop.

Comment: The for-loop writes the numbers from 1 to $# in the variable i. So in the body you grep in file with name 1 and 2 and there are no files with this names.

Comment: @RamanSailopal But the script must be generic so If anyone want to give 5 .out files, It can do the job

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thx for the comment. I added the expected result.

Comment: @TheSlater and how to deal with it, make the script taking the file in the ith argument given in terminal

Comment: In the script, $@ will print all the passed parameters and so you can do grep "enthalpy new" "$@" >> step.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present $I is referencing the iterations of the loop and so 1,2,3 .... These files cannot be found by grep and hence the error.

There are two approaches to ocercome this. $@ contains the parameters passed to the script and so you could try:

```
grep "enthalpy new" "$@" >> step.txt
```

Alternatively, if you want to loop through each parameter/file try:

```
for fil in "$@"
do
      grep  "enthalpy new" "$fil" >> step.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

To input filenames or any other variable you have to use $1 $2 $3 e.g. as the input for the script. It would work more flexible if you would drop them in a specific directory (let's say ./output) and call the script without variables in the parent directory - then it would be more flexible in terms of how many files you drop in there, without incriminating the variables and capturing input for code injection - the code should look like this:

```
for i in $(find ./output -name '*.out')
    do
        grep "enthalpy new" $i >> step.txt  
    done
```